# Is there a way in NetLogo to give turtles (of different generations) different ages?

Tags: netlogo

I want to modell the interactions of different tree species in a forest. To do so, I also have to simulate the growth/spread of the forest. 
There I face the two following problems:

1. I want the trees to reach a minimum age from which on they can hatch a new tree each year. But I only know how to make them reproduce every (e.g.) 20 years.
2. There is also a set age at which the trees are chopped town. The problem is, that when this age is reached, all trees of one breed are chopped down, even if their age should actually be less than their harvest-age.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
to go
 ask oaks [set age ticks]
end

to set-harvest-age 
 ask oaks [set harvest-age 240]
end

to spread 
ask oaks [
if (age mod 30 = 0) and (count oaks > 1) [hatch-oaks 1 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor set age 1]]]
end

to chop-down 
 ask oaks [if (age >= harvest-age) [die]]
end
```

The "set age 1" in "spread" does not seem to work. Maybe someone of you has an idea. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is the process order here. Every time `go` is called, all oaks will set their age to the current `ticks`. That includes any new saplings that you've hatched, so even if their age was 1 when they hatched, those saplings would instantly be set to the same age as all other oaks (which is just the number of ticks. Instead, you should use your `oaks-own` (or whatever species you want) variable to track the age of each individual turtle by incrementing it every tick rather than setting it *to* the ticks.

Additionally, it's probably better to use `go` or a similarly named procedure to act as the scheduler to call all the other relevant procedures. For example, check out these setup chunks:

```
breed [ oaks oak ]
oaks-own [ age harvest-age ]

to setup
  ca
  spawn-oaks
  reset-ticks
end

to spawn-oaks ; setup procedure
  create-oaks 10 [
    set shape "tree"
    set color green
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    ; Set the harvest age
    set harvest-age 100
    ; Randomly choose the age of the first generation
    ; to be somewhere between 50 and 75
    set age 50 + random 25
  ]
end
```

This creates 10 oaks with a an age randomly between 50 and 75. It also sets their harvest age. Now, use a procedure to increase every oak's individual age by one each tick:

```
to get-older ; Oak procedure
    set age age + 1
end
```

Then, something to have them start creating saplings when they reach maturity. I've included an `if any? other oaks-here` qualifier so that the population size doesn't immediately explode (as saplings can only survive on a patch without an established oak), but you would limit that growth in whatever way makes sense for your model.

```
to spread ; Oak procedure
  ; Get living, mature oaks to spead saplings nearby
  ; only some years (to avoid population explosion)
  if age > 30 and random 50 < 5 [
    hatch 1 [
      ; set sapling age to zero, and have it
      ; move away from its parent randomly
      set age 0
      rt random 360
      fd random 5
      if any? other oaks-here [
        die
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Finally, your `chop-down` procedure should actually work without changing now that the `age` issue is sorted out:

```
to chop-down ; Oak procedure
  if age >= harvest-age [
    die
  ]
end
```

Now all that's needed is to use `go` to call those procedures in the correct order:

```
to go
  ; Use the go procedure to schedule subprocedures
  ask oaks [
    get-older
    spread
    chop-down
  ]
  tick
end
```

Bit of a silly example but hopefully will get you pointed in the right direction!